# How to Populate ComboBox from access db in C#

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I have the next combobox:

```
this.comboBoxProd.Enabled = false;
this.comboBoxProd.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.comboBoxProd.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Cameras",
            "------------",
            " Digital IXUS 850 IS ",
            " Digital IXUS 900 Ti ",
            " Digital IXUS 75 -NEW- ",
            " Digital IXUS 70 -NEW- ", etc.
```

I want to change it and take the values from a db.
My database name is bd1.mdb and in the table Cameras it has the following fields: CamID, Cameras, Warranty, Year. I am only interested in the "Cameras" field.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a closer look for ADO.NET operations with .mdb files [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx)

First,prepare your connection string

```
string connString = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\bd1.mdb";
```

Next step is to prepare your query

```
string query = "SELECT Cameras FROM Cameras";
```

You will need an adapter to bind datasource,in your case it's **OleDbDataAdapter**

```
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
```

Now you can use a **DataTable** object to bind into combobox

```
DataTable source = new DataTable();
```

Fill data into your source

```
dAdapter.Fill(source);
```

Your source is full with Cameras,now you can refer to your combobox control

```
combobox.DataSource = source;
```

DO NOT FORGET THAT you should that which field will be displayed in Combobox items

```
combobox.DataTextField = "Cameras";//from query
```

Comment: didn't helped me very much. i don't wont to modify the content of the database, i want to add content from it.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience,Bomboe when I was writing the entire answer,I should have deleted rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably want to add a valuemember to the combobox this way you can link back to the camera id. Try changing the query to:

```
SELECT CameraID, Cameras From Camers
```

Then add the cameraID to the value member

`combobox.valuemember = "cameraID"`

and

`combobox.displaymember = "Cameras"`.