# How to populate a combobox from a Access dataset / Database

Tags: c#, combobox, dataset

ive hit a brick wall on what to do next to populate a combobox from a data set currently i have. my database is call "PID2db.mdb" and the table is called "Customer"

```
        string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.PID2dbConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
        try {
            conn.Open();
            string strSql = "Select forename,surname from customer where [customerID] ='" + txtName.Text + "'";
             OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            cboName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cboName.DisplayMember = "forename";
            cboName.ValueMember = "surname";
        }
        finally {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

edit: added new code segments

Comment: ive looked at that previously and i just cant get my head around it, im very new to C#

Comment: Ok, Try with this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809845/how-to-populate-combobox-from-access-db-in-c-sharp .  If you have some error/problem, please add some code for review ;)

Comment: Ok, give me a moment. I'll try to add another example. I don't understand the where clause ... Your column name is CustomerID ? and you try search using a string?

Comment: oh dear im a idiot! the combo box is now filling thanks for your help! i feel so stupid right now :(

Comment: how do i go about making the combobox show both the forename and the surname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Form with:

1. Combobox named cboName
2. TextBox named  txtName

Try this :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadCustomerOnCombo();
        }

        private void LoadCustomerOnCombo()
        {
            string strCon = Settings.Default.PID2dbConnectionString;

            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string strSql = "SELECT forename &\" \" & surname AS FullName, surname FROM customer"; //WHERE [customerID] ='" + txtName.Text + "'";
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    cboName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    cboName.DisplayMember = "FullName";
                    cboName.ValueMember = "surname";
                }     
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtName.Text = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

If worked so please tell me how is the where, left commented at the moment, else there are any errors, you'll see inside the textbox.

Comment: works great! thanks slight ammendment tho, how do i go about making both the surname & forename appear in the combobox?

Comment: Great! I'm glad you helped. Always try to add more data and some piece of code to make it easier to find the right solution :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new DataSet, fill it with Data and finally set the ComboBox's [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx), [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember) properties. Here is the code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

            string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.PID2dbConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
            try {
                conn.Open();
                string strSql = "Select forename,surname from customer where customer id ='" + txtName.Text + "'";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "forename";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "surname";
            }
            finally {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: its still not setting the data into the combox and there are no error messages coming up

Comment: Your answer worth one upvote, but not saying that the string concatenation is a very bad practice worhts one downvote. Draw.

Comment: if you really have a field named 'customer id' then you need square brackets around that name `[customer id]`

Comment: added square brackets to no avail unfortuntally :/

Comment: @Steve, I've just copied the select command from the question. I decided not to change the select command

Comment: @Bunion, set the breakpoint in the adapter.fill method and go with the debugger forward.  Once the DataSet is filled, check the ds.Tables[0].RowCount property in the Quick Watch window.  How many records are in the DataTable?

Comment: @platon excuse me, but whenever someone propose code that concatenate user input strings to form a sql statement I can not resist and I have to write something to say that is not a good thing. Never do.

Comment: @Steve, it's ok, and you are right, I think you were right, I had to change the initial code ....

Comment: i got it sorted thanks for all the help! have marked the answer above this as correct