# c# Selecting data from 2 different tables in ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to select data from 2 different tables. I am using MS access and I want to display the data in combo boxes. What is the proper way to do this i've tried:

```
string query = "select ProductName, BranchID from Product, Branch";


        command.CommandText = query;


        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        while (reader.Read())
        {

         comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["BranchID"].ToString());
            comboBox2.Items.Add(reader["ProductName"].ToString());
```

Comment: make the query you want in access, and copy the sql .. that query could flood you with everything in product against every branch.

Comment: You don't need a data reader here. You can use a data adapter. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a working database query (test this standalone in MS Access to confirm)..

Then see the answer to this question: [How to populate a combobox from a Access dataset / Database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14241091/526737)